# Acoustic wave equation will be numerically unstable anyway?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, stability-theory, finite-difference-methods

Since acoustic wave is longitudinal, its equation is exhibited nonlinear. In particular, I derived an acoustic wave equation within uneven, varying pipe. It goes:

$$
m_{tt} (m_x)^2 -2 m_{tx}m_tm_x + m_{xx}(m_t)^2=0
$$

where $m$ is accumulated mass of air along $x$-axis.

Since I am attempting speech synthesis, the initial/boundary conditions are:

$$
m(0,x) = \rho_\text{atm}(V_\text{lungs} + \int_0^x A(0,\lambda) \space \text{d}\lambda)
\\
m_t(0,x) = 0
\\
m(t,0) = \rho_\text{atm}V_\text{lungs}-m_\text{exhale}(t)
\\
m_x(t,0) = \rho_\text{atm}A(t,0)
$$
where $\rho_\text{atm}$ is the atmospheric density, $V_\text{lungs}$ is the air capacity of lungs, $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the pipe (which models the space between articulators), and $m_\text{exhale}$ is the exhaled air mass.

The actual quantity to be picked up is the air density at the right end of the pipe. That is, $m_x(t,L) / A(t,L)$. $L$ is the length from the glottis to the lips.

I attempted solving this PDE numerically using finite difference method. I tried few stencils, for all which the solution blew up. Yet to think about it, denoting the grid coefficients by $h_t$ and $h_x$, each term of the equation has $h_t^{-2}h_x^{-2}$ coefficients, which will be factored out. As a result, the amplification factor (regardless along $t$ or $x$) will be independent to both $h_t$ and $h_x$. Does this mean the numerical solution will blow up anyway, regardless of the choice of stencils? Does this mean finite difference method is unusable here?